# Backbone.js inline templates not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I've created a backbone.js app which uses inline templates, example of below:

```
<script type="text/html" id="header-template">
<div class='header'>
<strong><%= name %></strong>
</div>
</script>
```

Then in the the View:

```
template = _.template($("#header-template").html());
```

In Opera this throws an error due to `$("#header-template").html()` returning null. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

**Update:**

The error I'm getting in the console is `Unhandled Error: 'App.view.header' is not a constructor`. When I update underscore.js and backbone.js to the latest versions I also get this error in Chrome.

The header is defined like this:

```
App.view.header = App.view.header || {} 

App.view.header = Backbone.View.extend({
...
});
```

and rendered like this in the router:

```
$('header').html( new App.view.header().render().el);
```

**Another update**

I've created a tiny backbone.js app which has the same problem:

http://goo.gl/KoOvq

Comment: Works for me using jQuery 1.7.2 and Underscore 1.3.3 on Opera 12.02, Buold 1578 (Mac)

Comment: Have you tried using a different content type? Say `type="text/x-underscore-template"`.

Comment: Does the template exist in the DOM at the time you're trying to call it? What happens when you run that in the console after the page is fully loaded?

Comment: The exact error I'm getting is 'TypeError: App.view.header is not a constructor' and the header view is defined like this: App.view.header = App.view.header || {}

App.view.header = Backbone.View.extend({

Comment: @muistooshort - I tried that but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: The header view is rendered like this:

$('header').html( new App.view.header().render().el);

Comment: @tkone - I just ran $('#header-template').html() in the console and it returned the html of the inline template. So it must not exist in the DOM when the App initially loads. Also when I run $('header').html( new App.view.header().render().el) in the console I still get 'App.view.header' is not a constructor.

Comment: That's because render is not a constructor. You need to instantiate and then call render: `(new App.view.header()).render().el` should do it. Render only works after the view has been created.

Comment: @tkone If you load this [app](http://goo.gl/KoOvq) and run `(new App.view.header()).render().el` in the console you still get 'App.view.header' is not a constructor.

Comment: Looks like Opera has problems with the sequence of loading your libraries. Can you try it without using head.js?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the template in a function and call it only when needed.

I like this way more because if you start to put your templates in another files they will be loaded only when needed, the way you are doing now they are loaded at the app start.

> template = function(variables){ return _.template(template, variables) }

Comment: I still get the error: `TypeError: App.view.header is not a constructor` when I wrap the template variable in a function. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Could you put your HTML and code in JSbin or JsFiddle ? because this looks like a namespace problem, and that is hard to pinpoint with a few lines of code.

Comment: I've created a tiny Backbone.js app which has the same issue: http://goo.gl/KoOvq

Comment: Here it shows `Inline template loaded` and no errors, looks like it's fine.